# What are the finite-index subgroups of $\mathbf{Z}_p^\times$?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Can we explicitly describe all finite-index subgroups of $\mathbf{Z}_p^\times$?

Also, if $H \subset \mathbf{Z}_p^\times$ is a finite-index subgroup, what can we say about the isomorphism class of $H$ as a topological group?

Comment: The structure of $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099514/units-of-p-adic-integers), and this says that $H$ are actually isomorphic to subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @SeewooLee: While I agree the answer to OP's question follows from your link, I think you might have misread "finite-index" as "finite".

Comment: @Bun: What are your thoughts? What do you know about $\mathbb Z_p^\times$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg You're right. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg $\mathbf{Z}_p^\times$ comes with subgroups of the form $1 + p^m \mathbf{Z}_p$, and it seems natural to guess that these are the only ones.

Comment: Good start. But there is also the subgroup made up of the roots of unity, right?

Comment: Right, so the next guess would be the ones I described together with a subgroup of the roots of unity.

Comment: ... and "together with" means we can also form direct products (of any subgroup of the unit roots with any subgroup of the form $1 + p^m \mathbb Z_p$).

Answer (score 1):

Can you find all the finite-index subgroups of $\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z_p$ where $p \nmid m$?  In particular, can you show a finite-index subgroup contains some $p^r\mathbf Z_p$, which is open in $\mathbf Z_p$, so finite-index subgroups are automatically open subgroups (using the product topology on $\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z_p$)?

If you can describe the finite-index subgroups of $\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z_p$ for $p \nmid m$, then you can turn that into a description of finite-index subgroups of $\mathbf Z_p^\times$ for $p > 2$, since $\mathbf Z_p^\times = \mu_{p-1} \times (1 + p\mathbf Z_p)$ as multiplicative groups and

a) $\mu_{p-1} \cong \mathbf Z/(p-1)\mathbf Z$ (non-canonically, just as $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times \cong \mathbf Z/(p-1)\mathbf Z$ non-canonically)

b) $1+p\mathbf Z_p \cong p\mathbf Z_p$ as topological groups by the $p$-adic logarithm, so $1+p\mathbf Z_p \cong \mathbf Z_p$ as topological groups by using division by $p$.

The case of $\mathbf Z_2^\times$ is a bit trickier since $\mathbf Z_2^\times = \{\pm 1\} \times (1 + 4\mathbf Z_2)$, with $\{\pm 1\} \cong \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ and $1+4\mathbf Z_2 \cong 4\mathbf Z_2$ by the $2$-adic logarithm, so $\mathbf Z_2^\times \cong  \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z \times \mathbf Z_2$.